# \vspace next page

Tags: spacing

I'd just like to add some vertical padding between two bits of text and `\vspace{Xcm}` works fine for this; however, if the text is at the end of the page, `\vspace{Xcm}` does not carry onto the next page.

Is there a command or package that will add padding that will always apply at least `Xcm` of space?

Comment: ````\vspace*````

Comment: @yo' An answer?

Answer (score 3):

`\vspace` is ignored at the beginning of a page. You ought to use `\vspace*` that works there.